# Difference between Running code from module and from sheet-based

Tags: vba, excel

I am facing a the following Issue:
I have two Codes, one is Sheet-based and the second is Module based. In the Module i am defining a range like this :

```
Dim see As worksheet
Set see = sheets("Sheet2")
Dim rega As range
Dim gh As Long
gh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
Set rega = see.Range(Cells(3, gh + 2), Cells(39, gh + 2))
```

Now the problem is, when i run the code from the Module using F5 it works fine, however if i call it from the commandbutton written in the sheet (Call  it doesn't work, and it seems that the problem is with the range.
Any ideas, what i am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Usually it should not give any errors. can you show What code have you written in commandbutton click?

Comment: it doesnt give error, it just doesnt define the Range, so the range is "nothing"

Comment: it's not related to what is written in the commandbutton, it's long code do a lot of different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unqualified range objects probably raising a 1004 error?

```
Set rega = see.Range(Cells(3, gh + 2), Cells(39, gh + 2))
```

Remember that `Cells` method, unless qualified by a parent `Worksheet` object, will always implicitly refer to the `ActiveSheet`.

Try:

```
With see
    Set rega = .Range(.Cells(3, gh + 2).Address, .Cells(39, gh + 2).Address)
End With
```

Comment: Thanks David, it helps to solve the problem. you were right. however the problem solved only after i changed Set see = sheets("Sheet2") to Set see = Thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet2").
Regards

Comment: Unless the code is in a worksheet module in which case it will refer to that sheet, even if it's not active.